# How can I toggle form element using ng-show in directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Lets say I have a simple form like so:

```
<form ng-submit="methods.submit(formData)" ng-controller="diamondController" name="diamond" novalidate>
    <help-block field="diamond.firstName"></help-block>
    <input type="text" placeholder="" value="" id="firstName" name="firstName" ng-model="formData.firstName" class="" required>
</form>
```

I then want to replace the directive element with a pre-defined template, but parse in the diamond.firstName to the field attribute:

```
_core.directive('helpBlock', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        scope : {
            field : '@'
        },
        require : '^form',
        replace: true,
        template : '<p ng-show="scope.field.$invalid  && scope.field.$touched" class="help-block">Field is required.</p>',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {

        }
    }
}]);
```

Do I have to do something to link 'field' to the actual form data? I can't figure this one out. I more or less just want to make it so that if the user clicks on the field and toggles out without filling in the required field, it shows the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind your field using bidirectional databinding (`=`) and get rid of the `scope` prefix in your directive template:

```
app.directive('helpBlock', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    scope : {
      field : '='
    },
    replace: true,
    template : '<p ng-show="field.$invalid  && field.$touched" class="help-block">Field is required.</p>'
  }
}]);
```

See [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WLiDRHwSSaN2kMX08YvN?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

**What They Do**

ngShow and ngHide allow us to display or hide different elements. This helps when creating Angular apps since our single page applications will most likely have many moving parts that come and go as the state of our application changes.

The great part about these directives is that **we don’t have to do any of the showing or hiding ourselves with CSS or JavaScript.** It is all handled by good old Angular.

**Usage**

To use either ngShow or ngHide, just add the directive to the element you’d like to show or hide.

```
<!-- FOR BOOLEAN VALUES =============================== -->
<!-- for true values -->
<div ng-show="hello">this is a welcome message</div>   

 <!-- can also show if a value is false --> 
<div ng-show="!hello">this is a goodbye message</div>   

<!-- FOR EXPRESSIONS =============================== -->
<!-- show if the appState variable is a string of goodbye -->
<div ng-show="appState == 'goodbye'">this is a goodbye message</div> 

<!-- FOR FUNCTIONS =============================== -->
<!-- use a function defined in your controller to evaluate if true or false -->
<div ng-hide="checkSomething()"></div>
```

Once we have that set in our markup, we can set the `hello` or `goodbye` variables a number of different ways. You could set it in your Angular controller and have the `div` show or hide when your app loads up.

All of the above can be used for `ng-show` or `ng-hide`. This will just hide something if the value, expression, or function returns true.

For more information **[Click Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-ngshow-and-nghide)**

Comment: This doesn't help me, I know what they do, but I seem to be defining the field in the wrong scope